# Can a whole iron:router route be re-rendered if one of its subscribed collections changes?

Tags: meteor, iron-router

Template helpers can obviously provide reactive data, but Collection transforms don't re-run on changes. So is it possible to trigger a complete route re-render? or complete template re-render?

Here's the helper, with transform I'm wanting to fully refresh:

```
Template.productEdit.helpers({
    'locationsInventory': function(_productId) {
        return Inventory.find({productId: _productId}, {transform: function(doc) {
                    doc.name = Locations.findOne(doc.locationId).name;
                    return doc; // Transform is Non-reactive
                }
            }
        );
    }
});
```

You can see I'm joining a 'name' from another collection onto the doc with transform. But of course this is non-reactive, so what if it were possible to completely re-trigger the route render if the 'Locations' collection changed?

Comment: It turns out I'm a massive idiot, because it was working all along. It was reactive, I just couldn't see it due to my UI dropdown replacement which was not refreshing. Apologies... :/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with [Tracker.autorun](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/tracker_autorun)

```
   Template.productEdit.helpers({
    'locationsInventory': function(_productId) {
             Tracker.autorun(function(){
                     return Inventory.find({productId: _productId}, {transform: function(doc) {
                    doc.name = Locations.findOne(doc.locationId).name;
                    return doc; // Transform is Non-reactive
                }
               })
            }
        );
    }
});
```

Or with [observe.](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/observe)

```
Template.productEdit.helpers({
    'locationsInventory': function(_productId) {
        return Inventory.find({productId: _productId}, {transform: function(doc) {
                 var query = Locations.findOne(doc.locationId).name;
                    query.find().observeChanges({
                     added: function(id, doc) {
                         return doc;
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        );
    }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately it just doesn't seem to work either way. Good suggestions though, I've been trying all kinds of things like this.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like this (untested):

```
Template.productEdit.helpers({
    'locationsInventory': function(_productId) {
        inventory = Inventory.find({productId: _productId}).map(function(doc) {
           docs = Locations.find(doc.locationId).fetch()
           return docs[0].name
        });
    }
});
```

I used `fetch()` since it's reactive (whereas `findOne()` isn't). `map()` is reactive too, so if either change the dependency will rerun.

Comment: Thanks, this is a great alternative syntax.

Answer (score 1):

You can include the other collection in the helper. It may seem like it doesn't do anything but it should make the helper re-run if anything in it changes.

```
Template.productEdit.helpers({
    'locationsInventory': function(_productId) {

       // Add this
       Locations.findOne(); 

       return Inventory.find({productId: _productId}, {transform: function(doc) {
                doc.name = Locations.findOne(doc.locationId).name;
                return doc; // Transform is Non-reactive
         }
      });
    }
});
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm now using this strategy for another aspect of my app. I made a 'Invalidator' collection with a single document that I update with  Math.Random(). I then reference this in my iron:router data, so that when I update a related collection I change the value to invalidate and cause the router to refresh its data. Works a treat!